# false keystrokes in linux only

Tags: linux, arch-linux, keyboard, console, input

I have an annoying issue, it's as if linux thinks I'm pressing the Fn key every second. doesn't happen in windows though. Its preventing me from logging into arch. I can enter my LUKS password fine, then after that I just get these ^@^@^@^@^@^@ characters repeating every second. Its the same characters that show when I press my Fn button. IDK what to do. It even does it with my laptop keyboard disabled. I have windows 10 and Arch installed on a Lenovo Flex 3. Anyone have any ideas? Just started doing this out of the blue. Its also really hard to search for.

I tried chrooting into Arch with the USB, but I cant even enter my LUKS password because of the repeating characters. They also show up in Vim.